# Multiple conditions with scanf in C

Tags: arrays, c, input, scanf, eof

TLDR: I need to check if the input I am scanning with scanf into an array is really an integer while using EOF.

I need to scan numbers into an array until EOF. I am doing everything with statically allocated memory, since I am quite a beginner and for now dynamically allocated memory is hard for me to understand. I am also using getc to get the "\n" input at the end (but this is not a problem - just saying this so you know). My first thought how to do it is:

```
while(scanf("%d", &number[i][j]) != EOF )
**some code**
```

But this solution doesn't check if the input is integer. For example if my input is.

```
1 2 3
4 0 5
2 3 a
```

the code doesn't stop, since the value of the last array is 0 until i scan a number into it. My solution to that is

```
while(1)
    if(scanf("%d", &number[i][j]) != 1)
        printf("Incorrect input.\n");
return 0;
```

but since the EOF is equal to -1, that means I am getting input even at the end of the file which I don't want. So is there any way to have more conditions comparing the scanf? For example (I know this doesn't work, but to help you understand what I mean):

```
while(1)
    if(scanf("%d", &number[i,j] != 1 && scanf("%d", &number[i,j]) != EOF)
        printf("Incorrect input.\n");
return 0;
```

but this "solution" takes the input twice. I also found some answers on this site suggesting to use other way of taking input instead of scanf but I need to specifically use the scanf function.

Comment: The usual approach is `while( 1 == scanf(...))`.  You can then use `feof` to determine whether there was an input error or EOF. Or you can do `while( (c = scanf(...)) == 1){...} if( c == 0) { /* report bad input and abort */ }  else { /* hurrah, EOF without input error */}`

Comment: Please use `{}` even when there is just 1 statement. Please indent your code. And please provide a [mcve], which you have checked does not give any compiler warnings even with warnings turned on. Like, `number[i,j]` should give you a warning about code with no effect.

Comment: As a general guideline, to handle input errors without too much hassle, read entire lines, then parse the line, and ask for a new line if there was a parse error. This is because input is inherently line based, your programs always waits for user input until user presses enter after an entire line.

Comment: I totally forgot you can assign the value of the scanf to an integer to check for multiple conditions. Thank you all for the help. Closing the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the return value of `scanf` into a variable of type `int` and then perform further tests on it later:

```
int val, ret;

while ( ( ret = scanf( "%d", &val ) ) != EOF )
{
    if ( ret != 1 )
    {
        printf( "Incorrect input.\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //input is ok, so do something with the input value
    DoSomethingWithValue( val );
}

//if this line of code is reached, then EOF has been encountered
```